# WPF ViewModel not setting value unless step through the code

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, viewmodel

I'm working in WPF .NET Framework 4.0

I have an object called Facility.  This class contains many other objects and collections of objects.  I'm not having the following issue with any other collection of objects.

Setup: I choose my facility from a list.  I initialize the ViewModel as follows:

```
    var facilityResults = _app.FacilityManager.Get(facility.Id);
            if (facilityResults.Success)
            {
                ViewModel.Facility = facilityResults.Data;
                ViewModel.Facility.PropertyChanged += DataChanged;

            }
            else
            {
                ViewModel.ValidationResults = facilityResults.ManagerActionResultCollection;
                return;
            }
```

My collection is defined as follows:

```
    public virtual ObservableCollection<FacilityNoticeDetail> FacilityNoticeDetails
    {
        get { return _facilityNoticeDetails; }
        set
        {
            _facilityNoticeDetails = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FacilityNoticeDetails");
        }
    }
```

Like I said before, this is defined just like any other collection of objects.  It's made virtual so it knows the reference to FacilityNoticeDetail.

Problem:

When I run this solution, even though I have data in database, that collection is empty.  All other objects load fine. HERE IS THE KICKER... If I step through the debugger and look at the facilityResults.Data object, the collection is there and will get set, but ONLY if I step through the code.

ADDITION

facilityResults is of type ManagerActionResult which is a custom class:

```
    public class ManagerActionResult<T>
{
    public ActionResultCollection ManagerActionResultCollection { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }

    public ManagerActionResult()
    {
        Success = true;
        ManagerActionResultCollection = new ActionResultCollection();
    }


    public ManagerActionResult(bool valid, string message)
    {
        Success = valid;
        ManagerActionResultCollection = new ActionResultCollection();

    }
}

    public new ManagerActionResult<Facility> Get(int id)
    {
        var result = base.Get(id);

        if (result.Success)
        {
            var facility = result.Data;

            CalculateFeePayments(facility.Fees);

            CalculateContractPayments(facility.Contracts);
        }

        return result;
    }


    public ManagerActionResult<T> Get(int id)
    {
        var result = new ManagerActionResult<T>() { Success = true };

        try
        {
            var set = _context.Set<T>();

            var entity = set.Find(id);

            result.Data = entity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.Success = false;
            result.ManagerActionResultCollection.Add(new ErrorActionResult(false, ex.GetBaseException().Message, NotificationSeverityEnum.ERROR, ex.GetBaseException().StackTrace));
            Log.Error(ex.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

All that is doing is using the context to bring back my Facility object with its associated data.  Please let me know if this is still not clear.

Comment: Is `facilityResults` the `FaciliyNoticeDetails`? I am not following why you provided that code? I think you are not providing the appropriate code to help us help you....

Comment: I have added some more code to explain the facilityResults it's basically just what the context object is bringing back.

Comment: You haven't provided the bindings for the xaml - that doesn't help either.

My strong feeling given the code is that it's an async issue, i.e. you are not getting the notification update from when you have actually loaded the data.

You are adding them manually, yet I don't see a call to the binding notification.

i.e. you're not telling your view that you have updated stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you have understood the point that Justin was trying to make.

If your collection is named FacilityNoticeDetails, then you need to change the statement

```
ViewModel.Facility = facilityResults.Data;
```

to

```
ViewModel.FacilityNoticeDetails = facilityResults.Data;
```

As BaconSah mentioned, you have not actually shown us how you bind to this collection from your view. You will need some sort of collection container like a listbox with the itemssource bound to FacilityNoticeDetails property on the viewmodel.

I guess I'm also making the assumption that you have hooked up your OnPropertyChanged code correctly.

Here's a nice sample project that you can download as reference material.
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mag200902MVVM/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2026

Comment: Thanks for your help.  My Facility object had a collection of FacilityNoticeDetails which is why I thought I could just set the Facility ViewModel and work from that but I did end up having to explicitly set a ViewModel.FacilityNoticeDetails instead.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. Yeah we would have needed to see more code to understand this. Basically you don't have to explicitly set a ViewModel.FacilityNoticeDetails. In your xaml code at the itemssource binding, you have to reference the correct object. e.g. <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Path=Facility.FacilityNoticeDetails} /> instead of just pointing to Facility or however you have done it. I'm also assuming that ViewModel class is assigned to the DataContext(of the window?)